# Animation node - How to change the shading (smooth or flat) of a series of splines?

Tags: animation-nodes, splines

I managed to create an animation with concentric circles in animation nodes, made from points in a circle that I duplicated inside an object output. I want to change the shading of the splines (normally in the active spline pane, the smooth toggle) to flat. I can't find a way to do this inside of animation nodes. It's not in the properties of the spline from points node, neither in the Object output. Is there a way ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your issue. If you want a more "flat" spline, you could just bring the "Resolution U" value (in "Active Spline" panel) down - which can be animated.

Comment: It's when I use and object for the bevel, the edges of the splines are smooths, even though my bevel object has hard edges. Keep in mind that the splines are generated in animation node and the «smooth» toggle in the active spline panel can't be toggled it seems, it's stuck when AN is running.